# undefined local variable or method `ver_datos' for #<MaximosController:0x667fd58>

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Me disculpan, pero debe ser al cansancio, no veo el error :(

**el controlador:**

```
class MaximosController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_maximo, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /maximos
  # GET /maximos.json
  def index
    ver_datos
    @maximos = Maximo.all
  end
....
```

ACTUALIZACION DEL MODELO (mismo error)

**el modelo:**

```
class Maximo < ApplicationRecord
end

Private
  def ver_datos
    puts 'dentro de ver datos'
  end
```

**el error:**

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-11-02 12:45:43 -0400
Processing by MaximosController#index as HTML
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 250ms



NameError (undefined local variable or method `ver_datos' for #<MaximosController:0x5525328>):

app/controllers/maximos_controller.rb:7:in `index'
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-11-02 12:46:22 -0400
Processing by MaximosController#index as HTML
  Rendering maximos/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Maximo Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "maximos".* FROM "maximos"
  Rendered maximos/index.html.erb within layouts/application (9.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 6686ms (Views: 6636.2ms | ActiveRecord: 3.0ms)


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-11-02 12:47:03 -0400
Processing by MaximosController#index as HTML
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 265ms



NameError (undefined local variable or method `ver_datos' for #<MaximosController:0x667fd58>):

app/controllers/maximos_controller.rb:7:in `index'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu modelo `Maximo`, el método `ver_datos` está definido como método de instancia, eso significa que deberías tener un objeto de máximo y luego llamar al método, algo como:

```
maximo = Maximo.find(params[:id])
maximo.ver_datos
```

Ahora, si la lógica de `ver_datos` no está relacionada con una instancia, quizás lo que necesites es un método de clase, para lo cual deberías definir tu método como `def self.ver_datos` en vez de `def ver_datos`, entonces luego desde tu controlador lo llamas con:

```
Maximo.ver_datos
```

Ojo que `Maximo` inicia con mayúscula, lo que significa que se llama a la clase, no a la instancia como en el ejemplo anterior.

Comment: Amigo, quedé peor, mejor me tomo un descanso!

Comment: Amigo, yo lo que quiero es llamar un método que haga una serie de cosas, por favor échale un ojo cuando puedas, de antemano Gracias!
Yo tengo esa misma lógica en otra aplicación mucho mas compleja y me funciona, pero no veo el error en esto.

Comment: @rrg1459 dudo que tengas la misma lógica en otro lado, no hay forma que el controlador "adivine" donde está definido el método al que quieres llamar. Respecto a tu edición, que el método sea privado no mejora tu situación (que a todo esto es con minúscula). Si agregas el código que supuéstamente es igual a éste, puedo indicarte cual es la diferencia con respecto al de la pregunta.

Comment: SI, ya lo vi mas claro, lo que necesitaba era un objeto de clase y llamarlo tal cual como indicaste Maximo.ver_datos, como te dije, ayer tenia el bruto al máximo. gracias!

Comment: @rrg1459 que bueno, entonces el descanso sirvió :D 
saludos